# Protractor drivers stable versions?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

What are the most stable versions of Chrome, FireFox, IE and Edge for protractor?
I'm currently using chromedriver 78 with Chrome 78, and works fine, but FF 57 with geckodriver 19 has some fleaky behavior, I'm trying to gather info on their official website but no luck, they only mention FF 47 which I already tried but doesn't work for me, I'm trying to use  IE and Edge as well..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest stable:

```
chromedriver: chromedriver_81.0.4044.69
selenium-standalone-server: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.26.0
```